# Current measurement in 12V LED circuit

Tags: led, data, datalogger

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn5tHp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Just purchased an Omega data logger, i'm very concerned with the readings I am getting out of it. As a start I just want to make sure i'm not crazy with just this one hook up. See picture. Just a 12V battery and a 12V 48W LED light, measuring current through a 100A 50mV current shunt on the positive side of the battery. Resistance in the circuit as measured at the end of the data logger leg is 0.2 Ohms. Voltage measured with a multimeter on the data logger leg is 190mV. At roughly 3.9 A that is correct, but on the voltage logger I read 0V on each channel I try. Is there something inherently wrong with my setup that could cause an issue? Omega is trying to tell me I wired something wrong. Thanks for the help i'm really lost on this one.

As a side note, when I connect battery voltage to channel 2 and current shunt voltage to channel 1 I read 12V on both channels.

The plate everything is mounted to is Lexan.

[image]

Comment: Your question is missing a schematic diagram (use the built-in schematic tool on the editor toolbar) and links to datasheets for the various devices. We can't guess.

Comment: the wiring looks correct, and as the data logger sees a low resistance it must be connected to the shunt,  I would expect 190mv  to register in the data logger.  maybe connect the logger to a different voltage source and confirm correct operation.

Comment: Added a schematic. Thanks I will try a different battery tomorrow. As noted in the schematic I also measured a steady 2.2mV while the circuit was on between the negative ring terminal junction and the completely unconnected bolt next to it. Not sure if that's relevant but I thought it was weird.

Comment: Model number of your Omega data logger?

Comment: OM-CP-QUADVOLT-30V

Comment: Your part number has accuracy of +/- 0.1% FSR; with 30 volt input that is +/- 30mV, not enough for your shunt to be read accurately.  It also has a common mode input range of 0 to 2.5 volt.  You will have to put an amplifier on your shunt.  Luckily you have 12VDC available to run an op amp!

Comment: Figured it out finally. I was mislead by two different sources into thinking that a 100A 50mV shunt meant you would read 50mV per amp. Now, the way I understand it, unless this is wrong as well, is that a 100A 50mV shunt is designed to show 50mV **AT** 100A. Therefore 50A would read 25mV and so on. So at 3.8 amps it would read 1.9mV, basically nothing. I am now ordering a 5A 100mV shunt specifically for the LED application. Probably what everyone was trying to say all along.

Comment: Handheld meter reads "ghost" voltage? Check for common mode EMI disturbence. Replace LED with normal light bulb (free of EMC) and test again. Different results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't tell the model number from your picture, but check the isolation or common mode range of your device.  I'm betting it can't handle the voltage difference between negative inputs.  Two choices: 
1. Arrange the circuit using one channel for each side of the shunt, with all three channels sharing a common ground, and subtract shunt low from shunt high to get your current.
2. Put your shunt on the return side of the battery.  This is the less attractive choice for accuracy because of the IR losses in the power wire, if there is a common ground in the logger.  If there is some isolation between the low side of the channels, you will still want a separate wire from the low side of the shunt to the logger to avoid this effect.

The shunt's current rating value depends on your logger resolution and your expected load times.  At 30 A, you will have 15 mv, so you will dissipate 450 mW in the shunt.  Lower current shunts have progressively higher resistance so you would dissipate more power when at 30 A.  If you are going to be at 30 A continuous, I would agree that you should get a 50A shunt, but if you only expect short excursions to 30 A you can go lower.  Go with the lowest power rating you can (highest resistance).  You might try using the common ground approach and set the  logger channel to its highest gain (lowest input voltage range).  You probably need a resolution of at least 1% of your shunt voltage (500 uV) to read the current and get usable information.  If the channels all have the same range and resolution, you need 16 bits of resolution to measure 12 V and the shunt with the same gain.

Your part number has accuracy of +/- 0.1% FSR; with 30 volt input that is +/- 30mV, not enough for your shunt to be read accurately. It also has a common mode input range of 0 to 2.5 volt. You will have to put an amplifier on your shunt. Luckily you have 12VDC available to run an op amp!

Comment: Just checked and saw that the shunt I am using is rated for 60-100A and is specified for 50mV at it's rated current, so perhaps 100A shunt is too big? I read that shunts in extended use should only be loaded to 2/3 of their capacity so I tried to pick one that met or exceeded that requirement. Some of the currents we will be measuring may be as high as 30A.

Comment: So would a 10A 50mV such as the 20M10A50 from Ram Meter http://www.rammeter.com/ram-meter-20m10a50-10-amp-50-dcmv-dc-current-shunt.php be better for the LED application as pictured? Would a 10A 100mV be even better? If i understand correct the greater resistance of a 100mV shunt would provide even finer resolution, correct?

Comment: You are correct.  The shunt is just a sense resistor, and you lose a little voltage on your load as the resistance gets higher.  Do keep this in mind: a 10 A, 100mV shunt drops only 40 mv at your nominal 4 amp load.  When you go to a 30 amp surge, the shunt will have 300 mv across it, and will heat up if sustained (300 mV * 30A = 9W)  which is nine times the nominal rating. (100mv * 10 amp = 1W).  Not a problem for a fraction of a second, but if allowed to overheat it may fuse and will probably change value.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a lot of problems with your setup;

- trying to measure 4A on a 50mV/100A shunt only yields 2mV which is probably too small.

In any case, I think it's a waste of time.

A scope with a 40mV/4A shunt (10mOhm) would make more sense then use that on a scope vertical (1:1) with V horizontal will give you the VI curve.

I know what you should expect in the forward direction for Vf with a 12V 48W Luminaire.

each 3V shunt array is 12W will have an ESR of approx 1/12 Ω and 4 series equivalent LEDs yield 4/12 Ω  ~ 0.3 Ω *+/-xx %*

The equation to use is **Vf= Vth +I*ESR**

- I=4A, Vf~12V @ rated current (~4x3V)
- from my research Vth=2.75V ( asymptotic threshold  @85'C (whereas datasheets often show @25'C)
- ESR= 0.3Ω from above (rounded down)

[image]

Unless it has builtin circuit fo CC regulation!